# Is there any words or technical phrases describing the things that do not belong to a specific cluster of things?

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose we have 20 things;

We form a cluster encapsulating 15 items of these 20 things.

So, we would have 5 things that do not belong to that cluster of things.

I was wondering if  I can  refer to the remaining 5 objects as

- ex-cluster things

or

- non-clustered things

If not, how could I describe them?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example:  perhaps the things are "cows" and the cluster is "a herd"....  But that is my example not yours.  What are the things in your specific case?

Comment: @JamesK Thank you James, I was afraid my question would come off too technical. I am talking about abstract modeling in mathematics. For instance, suppose you have 20 nodes representing 20 entities of a system. Also, suppose that 15 of them are clustered since the share a specific property. Something along this context. I hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the term

> **outlier**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1.1** A person or thing differing from all other members of a particular group or set.

for something that lies outside the norm.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/outlier).

Comment: This works if the items not in the cluster are significantly different from those in the cluster in some way *apart from being in the cluster*.  So if you have 15 knives and three forks and 2 spoons, and you cluster the 15 knives, you *might* say that the forks and spoons are outliers.  But if you have 20 knives, and you cluster 15 of them as "My knives" and five are left, then the 5 remaining are not outliers.  I'm not sure that is very clear, but I know what I mean.

Comment: @JamesK it turns out that the OP is asking about data points, not cutlery.